# How to setup a 10Gbit/s network with Ubiquiti Dream Machine Pro

Tags: networking, 20.04

I installed a 10Gbit/s network card into my "ubuntu server 20.04" server today. But I'm not seeing the performance I would expect. The network card I installed is the asus xg-c100c, which is a base-t/ RJ45 network card.

I have a network connection, and yes it is connected to a 10Gbit/s capable device (Unifi Dream Machine Pro with SFP+ to RJ45 plug).

It also looks like the OS thinks there is a 10Gbit/s connection when I run the following commands:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C network
  ... (some other card are up here)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AQC107 NBase-T/IEEE 802.3bz Ethernet Controller [AQtion]
       vendor: Aquantia Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 02
       serial: 04:42:1a:3c:78:9b
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress pm msix msi vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atlantic driverversion=2.4.3.0 duplex=full firmware=3.1.88 ip=10.0.0.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:b1440000-b144ffff memory:b1450000-b1450fff memory:b1000000-b13fffff memory:b1400000-b143ffff
```

and

```
~$ ethtool enp1s0

Settings for enp1s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            10000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
                            5000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            10000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
                            5000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000005 (5)
                   drv link
    Link detected: yes
```

```
~$ networkctl
IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo              loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp7s0          ether    off         unmanaged
  3 enp1s0          ether    routable    configured
  4 docker0         bridge   routable    unmanaged
  6 veth2b97547     ether    degraded    unmanaged
  7 br-cdecd710286b bridge   routable    unmanaged
 10 vethb068640     ether    degraded    unmanaged

7 links listed.
```

What I tried to bench my setup:

- Starting a copy using samba on two separate windows pc's, both reaching ~55MB/s
- Starting a copy using samba on one windows pc, while also starting a scp command on my MacBook both reaching the same ~55MB/s

The content I was copying is located on a Samsung M.1 SSD.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to make changes to the OS so it can handle the 10Gbit/s?

Comment: No, they both have a 1Gbit/s network card, but both are connected to a separate port on the UDM-Pro, so the Windows PC's and MacBooks should be able to connect all at the same time with 3x 1Gbit/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this was not working and it is a sad one. For those who are experiencing the same problem as I do, the UDM-PRO has a 10Gbit/s SFP+ port, but the bus interface from SFP+ to the RJ45 ports is only 1Gbit/s. Here is a [diagram](https://ubntwiki.com/_media/products/udm-pro/udmp_unofficial_block_diagram.png).